# ethereum-cryptography.js Problem recovering public-key from signature

Tags: public-key, signature

Based on the following from ethereum-cryptography documentation:

```
Upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0:

secp256k1 module was changed massively: before, it was using noble-secp256k1 1.7; now it uses safer noble-curves. Please refer to upgrading section from curves README. Main changes to keep in mind: a) sign now returns Signature instance b) recoverPublicKey got moved onto a Signature instance
```

Although the signature is verified, I can't convert the returned object from sig.recoverPublicKey(msg) to the original publicKey hex format:

````
import { secp256k1 as secp } from 'ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1'
import { keccak256 as keccak } from 'ethereum-cryptography/keccak.js'
import { toHex, hexToBytes, utf8ToBytes } from 'ethereum-cryptography/utils'

const privateKey =
  '6f4025482d0aca9045f03a49256fdea43b6aefa33ec2b074be182aae04596120'
const publicKey =
  '02e8d8cf85e7bd4c249fd54daf9883467e87c57c000aa33d0e67dedd431e81832c'
const msg = 'Hello world!'
const msgByteArr = utf8ToBytes(msg)

const signature = secp.sign(keccak(msgByteArr), hexToBytes(privateKey))

const derivedPublicKey = signature.recoverPublicKey(toHex(msgByteArr))

console.log(secp.verify(signature, keccak(msgByteArr), publicKey)) //true
console.log(derivedPublicKey.toHex() === publicKey) //false!!!


```
````

Answer (score 1):

below is how i retrieve the public key using secp256k1 module on version 2.0

```
    function hashMessage(message) {
      return keccak256(utf8ToBytes(message));
    }

    async function signMessage(msg, privateKey) {
      return secp256k1.sign(msg, privateKey);
    }

    async function tst() {
      let msg = "test";
      const privateKey = <PRIVATE_KEY>; 
      let sign = await signMessage(hashMessage(msg), privateKey);

      console.log("publicKey: ",sign.recoverPublicKey(hashMessage(msg)).toHex());
    }
```

hope that works

Answer (score 0):

Same question here.

I started Alchemy University, and the first project should consist of receiving the signature from the user and, with that recovering the public key to be able to move funds for a particular address.

However, having the following signature, I am not able to retrieve the public key:

````
signature Signature {
  r: 47280888384242497109439486996523476252709515294379363283793036907373634667272n,
  s: 14094496101796106978990081669744084584839684113670443481146858170562046119959n,
  recovery: 1
}
```

Hopefully, someone can help with this newbie question :)
````

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to hash your message before passing it into the `recoverPublicKey()` method. Modify to:

```
const derivedPublicKey = signature.recoverPublicKey(toHex(keccak(msgByteArr)))
```